# Is a Regenerated Creature Removed from Combat?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say my opponent attacks me with a creature.  I use a burn spell to deal lethal damage, then he regenerates it.  Is it removed from combat at that point or does it still deal damage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, when a creature is regenerated, it is removed from combat.

The exact wording of the rule ([701.12a](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Regeneration)) is

> If the effect of a resolving spell or ability regenerates a permanent, it creates a replacement effect that protects the permanent the next time it would be destroyed this turn. In this case, “Regenerate [permanent]” means “The next time [permanent] would be destroyed this turn, instead remove all damage marked on it and tap it. **If it’s an attacking or blocking creature, remove it from combat.**”

Answer (score -6):

If I recall correctly creatures regenerate tapped.  That pretty much removes them from combat.

Comment: Why would tapped creatures be removed from combat? Heck, I tap my attackers and they are very much in combat.  As far as I know I can even defend with an untapped creature (such a tim the prodigial sorceror), blocking an attacker and then tapping it to deal damage. - That tapped Tim still blocks, even if it deals no combat damage. It still is in the fight). So purely on **tapped**: No. That is not enough.

Comment: @Hennes Note that Tim will still deal combat damage, they removed the rule that tapped blockers don't deal combat damage a while ago

Comment: Ah. I missed that. Then again, I still have decks with interrupts which I play as instants. (Nobody expects the Spanish.... uhm. Nobody expects the red elemental blast).